# Updating customized orchard to latest version

Tags: git, orchardcms

My team and I have checked out orchard 1.7.2 a few months ago and added many modules/features to the solution. Unfortunatly at the time we didn't set any git 'upstream' remote to orchard's source nor did we version orchard's source code.

I would like to change the way we follow evolutions in orchard source code by setting things properly.

The way I see it:

- **If possible, we would like to keep our git history** ;
- We need to set up a git remote pointing to https://git01.codeplex.com/orchard (orchard's source code) to keep track of orchard's latest updates in a few git commands ;

So that updating to the latest version would be as simple as:

```
# Update local repo's master to raw latest orchard
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master

# Update development branch, merge changes and adapt custom code
git checkout dev
git merge master
#update code and run tests
git commit -m "updated orchard from 1.7.2 to 1.8.0"
git push origin
```

How would you proceed, knowing that currently:

- Our project is hosted on BitBucket ;
- It contains only one branch, master ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right, your work is heavily based on the orchard-source. To keep the things simple you may just create a second remote for orchard (which only tracks the remote's master-branch) like this:

```
git remote add -t master orchard https://git01.codeplex.com/orchard
```

After that you're able to fetch or pull from that "new" remote. You may consider doing the "pulling in" from a special "integration"-branch to have more freedom within your master.

In this example I'm merging the `1.8.x`-branch into a integration branch:

```
$ git checkout -b integration
Switched to a new branch 'integration'
$ git pull -f orchard 1.8.x:integration
From https://git01.codeplex.com/orchard
 + 74136b6...37e9a33 1.8.x      -> integration  (forced update)
```

But be **aware** the normal merge will fail since your codebase can't be matched with orchard's codebase - they rely on different commit-ids. This is why you need to use the `--force`-flag which disables the id-check and merges the stuff like hell.

After that - of course - you'll have a lot of merge-conflicts to solve.

To avoid the trouble with the merge-in in the future i'd recommend you to fork the orchard-repository and do the merge-in the other way round. Merge your project into the orchard-fork. Then you'll be able to rebase on future orchard-commits.

Comment: Which means you're getting merge-conflicts?

Comment: `git branch orchard-master orchard/master` then `git merge --no-commit -s recursive -Xtheirs orchard-master`, and all my files are conflicted even though the diff shows no difference (even line endings, I played a bit with autocrlf to be sure).

Comment: Can you gist a relevant clip with `--stat`?

Comment: I downloaded orchard's 1.7.2 source from [here](https://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/view/115110) and commited it to local master. Now I try to identify which commit in orchard's master branch matches this release (no helpful tag associated). Here's the result of `git merge --stat --no-commit -s recursive -Xtheirs 01b6667d6d79 > output.log 2> error.log`: [output.log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd28a47e48b433914cf6), [error.log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c9221559c9134169fa01). Note that `--stat` isn't adding anything to the output. `git status` shows all files are "both added".

Comment: did you recently try to merge it into a different branch? I'll investigate where the error comes from. :)

Comment: Nope ! Steps to reproduce: download orchard 1.7.2 source code (zip file), extract, create a new git repo from this (master contains zip's content). Add remote to orchard's master, fetch, create orchard-master branch tracking this remote. Merge with the above command. I use msysgit. Thanks for your time...

Comment: I tested and verified pulling in - therefore the answer is updated. I could not reproduce the `error: addinfo_cache failed...`, but after the code-dive i can tell, the error is invoked if the file-paths in the cache differ from the (assumed) files, during a recursive merge.